# Severity of plagiarism

Tags: citations, plagiarism

In my [previous question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/194533/accused-of-plagiarism-in-my-master-thesis-which-i-submitted-two-years-ago-what) I asked about being accused of plagiarism.

Finally, the examiners have sent me the pages where I have not put the sources. These are 8 pages in total where I accidentally forget to cite due to some family stress and lack of knowledge about plagiarism .

As far as I remember I have put some pages in my thesis for reading purpose and forget to remove it from there due to my own carelessness.

What should I write in my answering statement to retain my degree?

Comment: There will be a meeting expected in near future. But I have to give a Statement in written why I not marked citiation.

Comment: @Buffy I want to know what should I write in my statement

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're saying you did. Do you have 8 pages that you copied from another source? Or are there 8 pages where you are missing all citations? Or are there 8 pages where you missed an occasional citation?

Comment: I copied these 8 pages and not cited. These pages I copied just for the Reader to read the addtional information about background. Infact these pages I put for my own reading and forget to remove these Page before submission.

Comment: If I were on the student integrity committee considering this case, I would not have found this explanation plausible. But it is between you and your university.

Comment: You submitted your thesis and didn't realize that 8 of the pages weren't your own? I don't think there is any reasonable way to explain that.

Comment: I didnt say that I didnt realise. I wrote that I forget to cite it. That is the main point. I put these pages as for my own reading and then forget to remove it. Or the other way I ca say that it only for the reading purpose to get addtional background about the topic.

Comment: "*I forget to cite it*" "*forget to remove it*" If you wanted to remove it, then why would you need to cite it?  These two statements seem contradictory; it seems that one or both of them are false.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accused of plagiarism in my master thesis, which I submitted two years ago. What now?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/194533/accused-of-plagiarism-in-my-master-thesis-which-i-submitted-two-years-ago-what)

Comment: This question is a clarification of the linked question above. I voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: "That is the main point. I put these pages as for my own reading" This is not something that anyone normally does (copy-pasting several pages from some other source into their thesis instead of, I dunno, printing them out or saving them into a separate file) and it's unclear why you would do this, so you'd need to come up with a very convincing explanation for this. (I cannot think of any myself.) Especially if you happen to have had such bad luck that the pages that you put there for your own reading happen to have landed into contexts where they fit in seemlessly with the rest of the text.

Comment: Also the fact that you have two unrelated reasons for doing this (family stress and lack of knowledge), when either one would make the other irrelevant, makes me think you are just making excuses.

Comment: Because this is my first research work in the form of thesis. That is why I dont have enough pladgirism knowldge. And also have a family stress

Comment: Sorry, we can't give individualized advice; you should try to rephrase your question so that other people could potentially have the same problem in future and benefit from this post. Beyond that, the only answer to "what should I write" is "an explanation of what happened"; there is no magic formula that will get you out of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Lack of knowledge about the plagiarism" but if you only mean that you mistakenly left it in rather than that you don't understand plagiarism, then you could say that.

You could also mention your stress based on family issues. I note that you haven't mentioned stress before, nor its nature. I don't suggest you add it here, but you might need to in your letter.

But, I suggest that you be honest in all things. Describe your process and how it failed. Offer to make suitable corrections.

I can't guarantee anything about the outcome. Hopefully you will be able to have a meeting. Answer honestly. Carelessness is bad but better than evil intent. Carelessness amplified by stress might get you forgiveness. Good luck.